# Two struct tm info called by separate localtime returns the same value

Tags: c, time

I have this test code:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <time.h>
  3 
  4 int main() {
  5     struct tm *info1;                                                                                                                                      
  6     struct tm *info2;
  7     unsigned long i = 100000000;
  8     unsigned long j = 200000000;
  9     
 10     info1 = localtime((time_t *) &i);
 11     info2 = localtime((time_t *) &j);
 12     
 13     printf("%s(): info1->tm_sec = %d\n", __func__, info1->tm_sec);
 14     printf("%s(): info1->tm_min = %d\n", __func__, info1->tm_min);
 15     printf("%s(): info1->tm_hour = %d\n", __func__, info1->tm_hour);
 16     printf("%s(): info1->tm_mday = %d\n", __func__, info1->tm_mday);
 17     printf("%s(): info1->tm_mon = %d\n", __func__, info1->tm_mon);
 18     printf("%s(): info1->tm_year = %d\n", __func__, info1->tm_year);
 19     
 20     printf("%s(): info2->tm_sec = %d\n", __func__, info2->tm_sec);
 21     printf("%s(): info2->tm_min = %d\n", __func__, info2->tm_min);
 22     printf("%s(): info2->tm_hour = %d\n", __func__, info2->tm_hour);
 23     printf("%s(): info2->tm_mday = %d\n", __func__, info2->tm_mday);
 24     printf("%s(): info2->tm_mon = %d\n", __func__, info2->tm_mon);
 25     printf("%s(): info2->tm_year = %d\n", __func__, info2->tm_year);
 26     
 27     
 28 
 29     return 0;
 30 }
```

The output is:

```
main(): info1->tm_sec = 20
main(): info1->tm_min = 33
main(): info1->tm_hour = 3
main(): info1->tm_mday = 4
main(): info1->tm_mon = 4
main(): info1->tm_year = 76
main(): info2->tm_sec = 20
main(): info2->tm_min = 33
main(): info2->tm_hour = 3
main(): info2->tm_mday = 4
main(): info2->tm_mon = 4
main(): info2->tm_year = 76
```

Lines 7 and 8 are actually timestamps (seconds since Epoch) as unsigned long passed from a calling function (I just hardcoded it here).

Lines 10 and 11 is my concern. I need to obtain the `struct tm` info of the two timestamps `i` and `j`. Basically, I need to get the month of `info1` and compare it against the month of `info2`, etc.

Doing the prints on Lines 13 to 25, `info1` and `info2` returns the same value (i.e same seconds, same minutes, same hours, etc).

Two questions:

1. Why do they have the same values?
2. How should I obtain different values of `info1` and `info2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

localtime() ->  Its return value points to a statically allocated struct which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.
So Use localtime_r() which stores the data in a user-supplied struct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
   #include <time.h>

   int main() {
      struct tm info1;                                                                                                                                      
      struct tm info2;
     unsigned long i = 100000000;
      unsigned long j = 200000000;

     localtime_r((time_t *) &i,&info1);
       localtime_r((time_t *) &j,&info2);

      printf("%s(): info1->tm_sec = %d\n", __func__, info1.tm_sec);
      printf("%s(): info1->tm_min = %d\n", __func__, info1.tm_min);
      printf("%s(): info1->tm_hour = %d\n", __func__, info1.tm_hour);
     printf("%s(): info1->tm_mday = %d\n", __func__, info1.tm_mday);
      printf("%s(): info1->tm_mon = %d\n", __func__, info1.tm_mon);
      printf("%s(): info1->tm_year = %d\n", __func__, info1.tm_year);

      printf("%s(): info2->tm_sec = %d\n", __func__, info2.tm_sec);
     printf("%s(): info2->tm_min = %d\n", __func__, info2.tm_min);
      printf("%s(): info2->tm_hour = %d\n", __func__, info2.tm_hour);
      printf("%s(): info2->tm_mday = %d\n", __func__, info2.tm_mday);
printf("%s(): info2->tm_mon = %d\n", __func__, info2.tm_mon);
     printf("%s(): info2->tm_year = %d\n", __func__, info2.tm_year);



      return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

[The documention](http://linux.die.net/man/3/localtime) clearly states why:

> The four functions asctime(), ctime(), gmtime() and localtime() return a pointer to static data and hence are not thread-safe.

In other words, you're getting a pointer to the same static struct owned by the standard library on each call. You need to copy the data in order to prevent this.